# user.getBirthday() returns null

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm using facebook sdk with android and when I use user.getbirthday it's always null.

I have added permissions

```
LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_birthday", "user_likes"));
```

and I request it like this

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {

    if (state.isOpened()) {

        Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                        Age = user.getBirthday();
                    }
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
}
```

but String Age remains null.

Ok I figured it out, it was simple really, on my app It was remembering my log in and I never had to click the log in button again, so after I added the birthday permission I never clicked the button, it was auto logging in without the permission

I just cleared the app data and logged in with facebook again and it worked.

Comment: If you have found a solution, answer yourself. It's a good practice

Comment: it told me i couldnt answer because my reputation isnt high enough, so it told me to edit my own question instead

Comment: It? Who? Anyway, you can always answer a question

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `executeAsync`()

```
Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                if (user != null) {
                        Age = user.getBirthday();
                }
            }

}).executeAsync();
```

Comment: I did, I just forgot to add it to my code example, sorry